# Detect/prevent uwanted changes to a file in git

Tags: git

Git offers plenty of tools to manage changes, to make, revert, move them around, merge and so on. Is there one to prevent critical files from being changed unintentionally (or more realistically, to detect that a file had deviated from a set "desired" state, so I could bring it up for a review)? Not necesarily a direct git feature but maybe a combination of them or a general strategy that would allow that?

Comment: What about Git hooks?

Comment: What about them?

Comment: @АндрейВахрушев like m0skit0 suggested, hooks are designed to achieve this kind of things in git. Check the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks).

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it. There are ways to invoke the check, but where in the repository do I put a reference that defines "desired" state? Where it wouldn't be a subject to an accidental incorrect merge, same as files I'm trying to protect?

Comment: You check the desired state at the hook. And no, it cannot be merged if you reject it in the hook.

Comment: That technically would work, but there doesn't seem to be a way to guarantee a hook to be executed every time for everyone. It is essentially up to the user to decide what goes into his /hooks/ and what doesn't. And leaving things to people is a recipe for an occasional failure. I'm looking for a solution with all organics removed from the process. A file that is never altered, unless someone steps up and explicitly takes responsibility for the change.

Comment: Any committed object (which has a hash ID as its "name") is frozen forever, so you can (1) make a commit that holds the desired state of the file, (2) tag that commit, and (3) access `tag:path` to get at the image of the file in the desired frozen state. If there's only one such file, you can simplify this by writing the file as a blob object and tagging the blob object: then `git cat-file -p tag^{blob}` will gain access to the frozen file.

Comment: @torek My scripts wouldn't be able to decide which tag to access then, it seems? Using sort of "frozen" files with no history is what I'm considering, but tags wouldn't add to that. Unless I misunderstood your point.

Comment: Git will store a frozen copy of file data—that's what files in commits are, after all. How you choose *which* frozen copy to compare the proposed-new-commit copy against is up to you. Using a known tag, e.g., `frozen-foo.data-v2` to map to a specific blob hash is a way to give the blob hash, which otherwise has an unpredictable and impossible-to-remember name, a predictable and easy-to-remember name. The rest is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

The git feature that accomplishes this is hooks.

You can use a local hook to check for unwanted changes at commit time.  This is as close to ideal timing as you can get - the sooner the problem is detected, the less work is built on top of the problem, and so the less the cost to fix it.

However, you can't force a user to run a hook in their clone.  (This is not a bug; in the general use case for git, strangers might clone your repo, and it would be a security problem for that to cause them to run arbitrary code of your choosing.)

You can provide the hook script, and you can even provide a script they can choose to run to install the hook.  Beyond that, the only thing you can do is encourage the usage of the script.

The main way to do that is to also have the check in a server-side pre-receive hook, so that pushes which violate the rule will be rejected.  Now the user has an incentive to run the commit hook, so they can catch and address the problem as early as possible, because until it's dealt with they can't share their work.

Comment: Thank you, but as far as I am concerned the hooks is an optional convenience mechanism. While it can be useful, I don't think it's meant to make even a remotely decent firewall.

Comment: We do in fact have pre-commit hooks in place, but are forced to disable them from time to time, due to long runnig issues with some of the checks or their dependencies. It looks good in theory, but it has proven to be extremely difficult to maintain an airtight perimeter around the repo, and not halt everyones work at the same time.

Comment: @АндрейВахрушев - I'm sorry you find the answer unsatisfactory, but that is the answer. To say that hooks are only a convenience mechanism is factually incorrect. As noted above, client-side hooks are at the developer's discretion (for good reason)l but server-side hooks can be, and are, used for exactly the purpose you describe by countless projects every day. If they don't work for you (or your hosting setup doesn't support them) then you can look at what features your hosting software does provide, but for what you're asking to do, I'm not aware of anything that isn't, at its core, hooks.

Comment: I'm not aware of such a function too, asked in case someone else is. That would probably be the answer, that there just isn't one. I see no point giving the hooks credit for what they rely on people and other software to accomplish.

Comment: @АндрейВахрушев - No, the answer is not that there is no mechanism.  The answer is that hooks are the mechanism.  Again, your distaste for that solution doesn't change that many, many projects solve exactly this problem using that mechanism.  To say that hooks 'rely on people and other software" to do what tehy do, simply is false.